# Sublime Text Side Bar issue

Tags: text, editor

first time using Sublime Text 2 and I dont have the side bar where you can upload the files that you plan on working with... is there something I need to do to access it? Do I absolutley need that bar to make a website? I want to use it because that is how I was taught and I don't really know any other way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can open the sidebar using command+k, and then command-b on a mac, or ctrl+k then ctrl+b on a pc.

["unofficial sublimetext docs"](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html?highlight=side%20bar)

Comment: Command? I believe that is "Control" on a PC, but it would be nice to include both.